# Non-linear least square minimization of 2 variables (different dimension) in python

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares, nonlinear-optimization

I have a function of two variables k and T. 
If have the value of the function for a number of (k,T) couple. However I do not have the same amount for each. For example I know the values f of the function at 2 T and 3 k:

```
F(k1,T1) = f1
F(k1,T2) = f2
F(k2,T1) = f3
F(k2,T2) = f4 
F(k3,T1) = f5
F(k3,T2) = f6
```

I also know the form of the function F:

```
def func(X, a, b, c, omega):
  T,k = X # The two variables
  n  = 1.0 / ( np.exp(omega / T )  - 1.0 )
  return a * k * n + b * k**2 * (n + 1.0)
```

I would like to find the value of a,b,c and omega that minimize the error. 
I tried with curve_fit:

```
k = [k1,k2,k3]
T = [T1,T2]
F[k1,T1] = f1
F[k1,T2] = f2
F[k2,T1] = f3
F[k2,T2] = f4 
F[k3,T1] = f5
F[k3,T2] = f6
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, (T,k), F )
```

However I get the following error (in my practical case I have 19 k values and 4 T values):

```
    return a * k * n + b * k**2 * (n + 1.0)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (19,) (4,)
```

Now if I create an array of higher dimension:

```
X = np.zeros((4,19,2))
for ii in np.arange(19):
  X[0,ii,:] = np.array([T[0],k[ii]])
  X[1,ii,:] = np.array([T[1],k[ii]])
  X[2,ii,:] = np.array([T[2],k[ii]])
  X[3,ii,:] = np.array([T[3],k[ii]])
```

and pass that:

```
def func(X, a, b, c, omega):
  T = X[:,:,0]
  k = X[:,:,1]
  n  = 1.0 / ( np.exp(omega / T )  - 1.0 )
  return a * k * n + b * k**2 * (n + 1.0)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, X, F )
```

then I get the following issue:

```
minpack.error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need an array of pairs of data with the input X (probably your original dataset already looks like that) and the corresponding output array F:

```
X = np.array([k1,T1],[k1,T2],[k2,T1],[k2,T2],[k3,T1],[k3,T2])
F = [f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6]
```

Then calling the `curve_fit` function is directly:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, (X[:,0],X[:,1]),F)
```

Alternatively you can use single arrays for the `k` and `T` and use them in place of `X[:,0]` and `X[:,1]`, but note that they should have the same dimensions since each element corresponds with the individual value of `k` and `T` of each observation/experiment. In other words, the index in the `k` or `T` array tells you the label of the corresponding observation.